# Getting 'undefined' After fs.stat

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that tests whether a file exists or not before editing it. I use fs.stat.

```
fs.stat('../fill/bower.json', function (err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('You don\'t have a ' + clc.red('bower.json') + ' file! Type ' + clc.bgBlack.white('touch bower.json') + ' to get started.');
        return;
    } if (stats.isFile()) {
        var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../bower.json', 'utf8')),
            string = '\n Dependencies: ' + json;

        fs.writeFile('../fill/README.md,', string, 'utf8');
        console.log('it\'s saved!');
    }
})
```

However, every time I run it (`bower.json` doesn't exist on purpose), it returns `undefined` before `You don't have a bower.json file!`. Why does this happen and how can I stop the function printing `undefined`?

Edit: for reference, here's my terminal window after running the command:
[image]

Why is `undefined` printed, and what do I do to have that not be displayed?

Comment: Same thing :/ I'm assuming since the file doesn't exist, it's registering that first and printing it, ignoring the `if (err)` statement.

Comment: That `undefined` is not coming from that function, I think you have to give us some more context if you are to get some help debugging. That said, for a script like this you might as well use the `Sync` versions of the `fs` functions.

Comment: Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/apizzimenti/4f183717ff8f84751425

Comment: Ok so here's the culprit, you log the result of `reading()` which doesn't return anything:
     `case '--readdeps':
        console.log(reading());
        break;`

Comment: Yep, @limelights and I cleared that up. I didn't realize that I was `console.log`ging `reading()`. I didn't mean to do that. But thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning nothing or `undefined` from your `reading` function.

[Gist for posterity](https://gist.github.com/apizzimenti/4f183717ff8f84751425)

Comment: How do I stop `undefined` from being printed?

Comment: If it's a command line script then research into exit codes, don't console.log your `fill` function or `fs.stat` function.

Comment: It's written in node, and the `fill` is the command to run the file the functions are stored in as an executable. The fs.stat function isn't console.logged and if `return` is replaced by `process.exit(0)` or any other exit code, the same `undefined` is returned.

Comment: Yes, all functions in javascript returns `undefined`, but when you use the `return` keyword you can specify the value. Therefore, if your `fill` function is not returning anything it'll still return `undefined`.

Comment: How do you suggest I fix the problem?

Comment: I put a gist in the comment thread on the original question, would you mind looking at that? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, as a figured, when you're passing `--readdeps` you **are** console.logging the `reading` function which, lo and behold, returns nothing.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.